# Regular expression that starts with a certain string and ignores those that contain a specific string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to write a regular expression in PHP that would match any string that contains 'search/site/*' but only if it does not contain the string 'ss_language'

Here is what I have so far: http://regexr.com?3416i
This successfully matches any 'search/site/*' including 'search/site' so now I need the bit that excludes any string that contains 'ss_language'

Thinking about this, it seems that I could just nest another preg_match to just look for the ss_language, but is that the best way to go about it vs. one single regular expression? Is this even possible with one regular expression? Here are some examples and what they should return:

- Pass - search/site
- Pass - search/site/cat
- Pass - search/site/dog?f[0]=im_field_technology%3A20858
- Pass - search/site/cat%20dog?f[0]=im_field_technology%3A20858
- Fail - search/site/cat%20dog?f[0]=ss_language%3Aen
- Fail - search/site/?f[0]=im_field_technology%3A20858&f[1]=ss_language%3Aen
- Fail - search/site/?f[1]=ss_language%3Aen&f[0]=im_field_technology%3A20858
- Pass - search/site/?f[0]=im_field_technology%3A20858&f[1]=im_field_technology%3A20875o
- Fail - node/23/edit

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm pretty new to these. Here is a failed attempt: http://regexr.com?3416f

Comment: What does `search/site/cat%20dog?f[0]=ss_langu%61ge` - pass or fail?

Comment: You don't need a regex to accomplish this, see my example below using a simple `strpos()` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a regex which would be slower. Use [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$status = (0 === strpos($url, 'search/site') && FALSE === strpos($url, 'ss_language'))
    ? 'PASS'
    : 'FAIL';
```

Check out the: **[DEMO](http://viper-7.com/GbVQFC)**

Basically what it does is it checks to see if the URL starts with `search/site` and if it does it then check to see if it does NOT contain `ss_language` and will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` or Pass/Fail in this example. Regex is not needed at all as you are just looking for substrings.

Comment: Thanks cryptic, this does exactly what I need with strpos instead of a regex, which is indeed faster, hence why I marked this the correct answer. It never occurred to me to just use strpos as the example I was building off of used regex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead to assert that the string does not contain `ss_language`

```
^search/site/?(?!.*ss_language.*).*$
```

If you just want a true/false answer to whether or not it matches then you don't really need the `.*$` (it would then only match `search/site` with the optional `/` given there is no `ss_language` anywhere in the string (short version):

```
^search/site/?(?!.*ss_language)
```

Comment: rvalvik, that works perfectly! Thank you. I marked up your answer but didn't mark it as the correct one only because the answer below that uses strpos instead of a regex does what I need but faster. But your answer is the correct regex solution so I wanted people to know that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://regexr.com?3417a for following regex:

`^search/site/?(?:(?!ss_language).)*$`

It's indeed using negative lookahead.

Comment: This regex (which is similar to the one above) also works. I don't have the rep to upvote you yet (too new to SO) but I wanted people to know that I tested it and it does work. Thank you!